# Como mantener useContext en varios componentes

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, react-hooks

**Problema**: Estoy realizando una aplicación en `react` en la que se necesita login, el problema que tengo es que al realizar un refresh de la página o un cambio a otra componente el `context` se vuelve a inicializar como `null` en vez de mantener el valor que se le asigna una vez el usuario se loguea, una vez se realiza el `onClick` del login se vuelve a poner en `null` su valor, a su vez obtengo un problema al hacer uso del mismo contexto en cada una de las componentes ya que no es posible hacer uso de este en funciones de `react` como `render()` o `componentDidMount()`

#Código `User.js`

```
import React from "react";


export const userContext = React.createContext('false');
export const setUserContext = React.createContext('false');
```

## Código `login.js`

Aquí es donde hago uso del `context` creado en `User.js` aquí se setea el `context` en función del usuario.

```
export default function Login() {

  const userInfo = React.useContext(userContext);
  const setUserInfo = React.useContext(setUserContext);
  
  const [usuario, setUsuario] = React.useState({});
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState({});

  console.log(userInfo);

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    await loginUser({

      usuario,
      password,

    }, setUserInfo);
    
  };

  if (userInfo != null) {

    return (
      <div className="App container">
        <div className="justify-content-center row">
          <h1 style={{ color: "white" }}>Ya estas logeado</h1>
          <button
            type='button'
            className="btn btn-warning"
            onClick={setUserInfo(null)}
          >
            Logout
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    
  }

  return (
    <div className="App container">
      <div className="justify-content-center row">
        <h1 style={{ color: "white" }}>Inicio de sesion</h1>
      </div>
      <Link to="/Register" className="nav-item nav-link active">
        Registro
      </Link>
      <div className="justify-content-center row">
        <form className="mt-5" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
          <label>
            <p>Username</p>
            <input required type="text" onChange={(e) => setUsuario(e.target.value)} />
          </label>
          <label>
            <p>Password</p>
            <input
              required
              type="password"
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <div>
            <button type='button' className="btn btn-success" type="submit">
              Iniciar Sesión
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Código `App.js`

Aquí es donde se encapsula el `context` pero por alguna razón se pierde siempre al realizar un refresh o un cambio de componente.

```
function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({});

  return (
    <Router>
      <userContext.Provider value={user} >
        <setUserContext.Provider value={setUser} >
          <div className="App">
            <Nav />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
              <Route path="/Login" exact component={Login} />
              <Route path="/Register" exact component={Register} />
              <Route path="/Noticias" exact component={Noticias} />
              <Route path="/Estadisticas" exact component={Estadisticas} />
              <Route path="/CompraVenta" exact component={CompraVenta} />
              <Route path="/Plantilla" exact component={Plantilla} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </setUserContext.Provider>
      </userContext.Provider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: ¿Estas importando `User.js` en cada uno de los componentes que lo consumen? saludos

Comment: @g.4 sí lo estoy importando pero se pierde ya que en `login.js` de momento es donde lo estoy usando pero además no es que haga ningún `window.replace` ni nada del estilo por que realmente ahora no se debería perder y si que lo hace.

Comment: Coloca las primeras letras de tus context en mayúsculas, es decir: `UserContext` y `SetUserContext ` y por lo tanto los tags en `App.js`  tambien deberían estar en mayúsculas para que react los tome como componentes: `<UserContext.Provider value={user} >` y `<setUserContext.Provider value={setUser} >`.  Prueba si eso te ayuda. Te dejo la documentación oficial https://es.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext